# Error CS0122 'Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C# and I want to use “AddForce” to apply force on a 3D object (sphere). I have the following C#-script that I try to run in Visual Studio 2019 (With Unity 2020.2.0b14):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Script14sept : MonoBehaviour {

    public float forceValue;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
                                0,
                                Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * forceValue);
    }
}
```

However, running this code results in an error:
Error CS0122 'Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Is there something wrong in the code or does it depend on another issue (e.g. using the beta version of Unity)?

Comment: Don't use [**BETA**](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta) versions of Unity unless you want to investigate the newest features. The version you have might still be full of (already solved) known issues and bugs ... You should rather stick to the latest [LTS](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases) version (currently `2020.3.18f1`)

Comment: However, it's the first time I see that ... doubt that this was changed for one of the beta versions and then suddenly worked again ^^ Odd thing ...

Answer (score -1):

The Component rb is set to private. Set it to public.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).